# How to serve a custom error page if the server is down?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, web, server

I have a website and want to serve a custom error page to my users if my server goes down. If the site is unreachable, like to say something like "we will be back soon for you". Is this possible in general or am I not able to serve anything without my server is up? If its possible how do I configure this?

I have a server hostet with Ubuntu 18.04 as OS and nginx as webserver.

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server is down either because the Nginx service is not running or your server is not reachable then you can't serve any content from that server because no connection can be opened by a client.

The only way to achieve the result you want is by running the client's connection through a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) before it reaches your Nginx web server. That way, if your Nginx web server is unreachable you can tell the reverse proxy to serve a static html file.

Alternatively you can use a service such as [CloudFlare](http://cloudflare.com/) which proxies and manages the traffic before sending it to your nginx web server. CloudFlare automatically shows a customized "Offline" page if your web server is unreachable. See [this image](https://xpoc.pro/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/test.png) as reference.